# Import csv which have numerics with comma as the decimal separator

Tags: stata, decimal-point

I have a 5 gb `csv` file which takes over an hour to import to stata.

The reason is, among other things, it is in the European format, i.e., it is a `;` separated file and numeric columns come with `,` as de decimal separator. For example:

```
V1  V2   V3
A   2,4  10,1
B   30   1,4
```

Problem is that `stata` assumes the numeric columns are string variables, thus, tries to import it in a really inefficient way (trying to declare the columns as numerics just give me missing values).

Is there a command/option where I input a different decimal-point separator, so the importing process goes faster?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this in one step?

Comment: No, I have tried to email the `Stata` developing team, but it is a very bureaucratic process to ask for anything. My conclusion, so far, is that, for the existing versions, it is impossible to do it without changing the source code to import excel files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the functionality you are looking for has been added to Stata 16. The command `import delimited` has new options `parselocale()`, `groupseparator()`, and `decimalseparator()`.

See `10/c` from **whatsnew15to16** below:

```
help whatsnew15to16
```

> 10. import delimited is the existing command to import data from 
>       delimited text files.  It has been enhanced.
>
>     a. It is faster.  It is 10% faster in general, and 2 to 4 times
>                   faster in some cases.
>
>     b. It detects delimiters better.  In addition to commas and tabs, it
>                 now detects pipes, colons, and semicolons.
>
>     c. New options allow numeric parsing based on locale.  The options
>             are parselocale(), groupseparator(), and decimalseparator().
>
>     d. Mismatched quotes in the imported file are reported so that you
>                 can fix them.

For the data:

```
A; 2,4; 10,1  
B; 30; 1,4
```

You could do the following:

```
import delimited "D:\data.csv", varnames(nonames) parselocale(es_ES)
```

or

```
import delimited "D:\data.csv", varnames(nonames) groupseparator(.) decimalseparator(,)
```

```
list

     +-----------------+
     | v1    v2     v3 |
     |-----------------|
  1. |  A   2.4   10.1 |
  2. |  B    30    1.4 |
     +-----------------+

describe

    Contains data
      obs:             2                          
     vars:             3                          
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  storage   display    value
    variable name   type    format     label      variable label
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    v1              str1    %9s                   
    v2              float   %8.0g                 
    v3              float   %9.0g
```

Comment: Thanks, but weird that stata took that long for such a simple and necessary change.

Answer (score 2):

If your data file looks like this:

```
A; 2,4; 10,1  
B; 30; 1,4
```

You could do the following:

```
import delimited whatever_filename.txt, delimiters(";") varnames(nonames)
destring v2 v3, dpcomma replace

list

   +-----------------+
   | v1    v2     v3 |
   |-----------------|
1. |  A   2.4   10.1 |
2. |  B    30    1.4 |
   +-----------------+
```

As of Stata version 15, there isn't a way of doing this in one step. I think the only other solution is to pre-process the data file by changing the comma to a period. Excel could do this easily.

Comment: Yeah, that is the main issue, doing it in one step. My problem lies on your first line, which imports V2 and V3 as strings, making the importing way inefficient.

Comment: You can carp at a solution if you can think of a better one!